# TFS template customization - missing assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gac

I have to customize TFS2010 default build proccess template. To work with Workflow Activity Library, I need to add a reference to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll. But the folder 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client doesn't exist in my GAC_MSIL folder or somewhere else.
I have VS Ultimate. Is there any settings or upgrades i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice one :-)

The file is in a hidden piece of your drive. And with hidden, I do not mean that you can get it visible by unhiding all system files! No, it it actually hidden behind the custom list of GAC registered assemblies you can see at C:\Windows\assembly.

What to do:
 1. Start windows explorer.
 2. Paste C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL in the location bar and press enter.

Et voila, there is your list of GAC assemblies in a file formatted list, you can copy to your project space, or reference from your project directly.

[image]

Super hidden!

Comment: To expand on this you can also use a free utility called Everything (http://www.voidtools.com/) that will let you locate files extremely quickly. This will help you avoid having to search to hard.

Comment: Ok, but what if it's not in this location either?